# Replace Double quotes with space

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

this is perhaps one of the most discussed topics here. I tried almost all the commands and other tweaks found here, but something doesn't seems to be doing well.

i would want to replace all the double quotes in my file with whitespace/blank

I'm seeing the below error when i tried to execute this command.

```
sed "s/"/ \''/g' x_orbit.txt > new.tx
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: can someone tell me how to define space in sed?

Comment: A space is just a space.  The real problem was using double quotes instead of single quotes.  Look [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close.  Just use single quotes, so the shell doesn't try to expand the metacharacters in your sed command:

`sed 's/"/ /g' x_orbit.txt > new.txt`

Comment: or `sed 'y/"/ /' x_orbit.txt > new.txt`

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) for example:

```
tr '"' ' ' < x_orbit.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The script you provided:

```
sed "s/"/ \''/g' x_orbit.txt > new.tx
```

means:

```
sed    # invoke sed to execute the following script:
"      # enclose the script in double quotes rather than single so the shell can
       # interpret it (e.g. to expand variables like $HOME) before sed gets to
       # interpret the result of that expansion
s/     # replace what follows until the next /
"      # exit the double quotes so the shell can now not only expand variables
       # but can now do globbing and file name expansion on wildcards like foo*
/      # end the definition of the regexp you want to replace so it is null since
       # after the shell expansion there was no text for sed to read between
       # this / and the previous one (the 2 regexp delimiters)
\'     # provide a blank then an escaped single quote for the shell to interpret for some reason
'/g'    # enclose the /g in single quotes as all scripts should be quoted by default.
```

That is so far off the correct syntax it's kinda shocking which is why I dissected it above to try to help you understand what you wrote so you'll see why it doesn't work. Where did you get the idea to write it that way (or to put it another way - what did you think each character in that script meant? I'm asking as it indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of how quoting and escaping works in shell so it'd be good if we could help correct that misunderstanding rather than just correct that script.

When you use any script or string in shell, simply always enclose it in single quotes:

```
sed 'script' file
var='string'
```

unless you **NEED** to use double quotes to let a variable expand and then use double quotes unless you **NEED** to use no quotes to let globbing and file name expansion happen.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` version:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/," ")}1' file
```

`gsub` is used for the replace
`1` is always true, so line is printed